# C#: Asynchronous delegates vs ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem when initiating many connections

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, amazon-web-services, threadpool

I have to send many web service calls out to delete a bunch of records in Amazon SDB (unfortunately, rows can only be deleted one at at time currently).

I am using Amazon's SDB c# library which does not use async WebRequests.

Currently I use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to queue up a bunch of calls (I configured my connectionManagement maxconnection to allow for a bunch of connections)
this works well..as the request is sent out, it blocks and another request is made.

Is this the wrong way to achieve this goal?  Should I be using async delegates and doing BeginInvoke and EndInvoke?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need to queue up some jobs (that don't return values directly) go with `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`. It's faster. The difference is covered in [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532791/whats-the-difference-between-queueuserworkitem-and-begininvoke-for-performi) (and some great blog entries out there.)

Answer (score 2):

Going trully async would require to abandon the Amazon library and roll your own, using BeginGetRequestStream/BeginGetResponse (which I would recommend). If you stick with the sync WebRequests, then use QueueUserWorkItem.