# Directly Inserting Bytecode

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way to dynamically insert bytecode directly into my C# executable? I'm looking for functionality similar to the [asm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/45yd4tzz(VS.80).aspx) keyword in C++. Obviously I know I can't insert x86 assembly instructions. I'd only be able insert IL Bytecode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`DynamicMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod(VS.80).aspx)s which basically do exactly this (you get a Delegate to invoke the code that you've generated with the dynamic method).

In fact, several framework parts seem to use them, including the compiled XSL transformations, the compiled Regular Expressions etc. They work very well and they are pretty performant (after the initial overhead for creating/compiling them).

Comment: You're welcome. Some interesting information can be found tagged here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dynamicmethod (and one sample by me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516119 ) - have fun! ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use **Reflection.Emit** directy - you must create an Assembly/Module/Class/Method and insert the IL on the method body.

--

With .Net 2.0 you can use **DynamicMethod** that can be compiled in a delegate, so you don't need to create the Assembly/Module/Class dynamically.

--

With .Net 3.0 you can use **ExpressionTrees** to dynamically generate the code and attach to a delegate.

--

Hope this helps.

Ricardo Lacerda Castelo Branco