# How do I call event handlers on the threads of the subscribers?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events

In my C++/Qt applications, whenever I want to raise a signal/event, I would simply do:

```
emit Event();
```

This would call all handlers for `Event()` on the same thread as the objects that subscribed to this event.

C# doesn't seem to offer anything like that, so how do I do this?

I have a class, let's call it `EventRaiser`, which has a `SomethingHappened` event and a method that raises the event when needed:

```
class EventRaiser
{
    public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;

    void RaiseEvent()
    {
        var anyoneWhosInterested = SomethingHappened;
        if (anyoneWhosInterested != null)
        {
            try { anyoneWhosInterested(this, new EventArgs()); }
            catch { /* we don't care */ }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that `RaiseEvent()` will call the handlers on the thread `RaiseEvent()` got called. But I need to call the handlers on the threads that subscribed to the event.

How do I do this?

I'm on .NET 2.0 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2459683/815938) was discussed before,

Answer (score 1):

In general this idea does not make sense because you can't arbitrarily interrupt running code on a different thread and inject an event. That architecture would cause high amounts of random breakage.

Make the subscribers handle the synchronization and marshaling. They know what thread they are running on and how to safely marshal a call onto it.

Consider capturing the current `SynchronizationContext` in the `SomethingHappened.add` handler and sending/posting the event to that `SynchronizationContext`. This only works if the subscribing thread has a meaningful context.

Comment: In Qt this goes through the event loop. The signal is dispatched to the correct thread later on. There's no interruption of running code involved. I guess the answer is "not possible in C#"?

Comment: I don't think Qt will ever interrupt a running thread. It might queue a message or an event but never will running code be interrupted. This is even more impossible with C++ than with C#.