# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem and EndInvoke

Tags: .net, threadpool

Do I need to call the EndInvoke on a delegate passed to ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem?

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532791/whats-the-difference-between-queueuserworkitem-and-begininvoke-for-performi/532820#532820) suggestion to call the ThreadPoolQueueWorkItem.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
    delegate { someDelegate(arg1, arg2); }
);
```

If i need to call endinvoke, how do I call it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't need to call it. In fact, you shouldn't :-)

You should only call EndInvoke to end an asynchronous invocation previously started by calling BeginInvoke.

In the code you have provided you are running the delegate synchronously from a ThreadPool thread.

This approach is just fine when you have a "fire and forget" requirement. However, if you need to retrieve output from the invocation it would be better to use BeginInvoke followed by EndInvoke.

Comment: Great.  That's what I needed to know.  I am doing the fire and forget approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, no, but according to MSDN you should to avoid potential memory leaks. Here's a [great blog post by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/09/asynchronous-fire-and-forget-with-lambdas.aspx) discussing the issue, as well as his helper class for fire and forget use cases.

Comment: You got the first part of the question.  I need to call it.  But how?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, in your example you don't need to because you didn't call BeginInvoke.