# QueueUserWorkItem with delegate does not work, but WaitCallBack does work

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

In the question below, I found this neat trick for calling QueueUserWorkItem in a type safe way, where you pass a delegate instead of WaitCallBack and an object.  However, it doesn't work the way one would expect.

[What's the difference between QueueUserWorkItem() and BeginInvoke(), for performing an asynchronous activity with no return types needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532791/whats-the-difference-between-queueuserworkitem-and-begininvoke-for-perform)

Here's some sample code and output that demonstrates the issue.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // doesn't work - somehow DoWork is invoked with i=10 each time!!!
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { DoWork("closure", i); });

    // not type safe, but it works
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(DoWork), Tuple.Create("    WCB", i));
}

void DoWork(string s, int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - i:{1}", s, i);
}

void DoWork(object state)
{
    var t = (Tuple<string, int>)state;
    DoWork(t.Item1, t.Item2);
}
```

and here is the output:

```
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:0
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:2
    WCB - i:3
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:4
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:5
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:6
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:7
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:8
closure - i:10
    WCB - i:9
    WCB - i:1
closure - i:10
```

Note that when using the closure to call QueueUserWorkitem, i=10 for ever call, but when using the WaitCallBack you get the correct values, 0-9.

So my questions are:

1. Why isn't the correct value of i passed when using the closure/delegate way of doing it?
2. How on earth does i ever get to be 10?  In the loop, it only ever had values 0-9 right?

Comment: Loop variable capture, again. Search stack overflow for that term.

Comment: @usr Or, you could find one of the duplicates and vote to close.  That would be the more effective thing to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answers to both of your question are related to the scope of the closure when you create the anonymous method.

When you do this:

```
// Closure for anonymous function call begins here.
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // i is captured
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { DoWork("closure", i); });
}
```

You're capturing `i` across the *entire loop*.  That means that you queue up your ten threads *very* quickly, and by the time they start, the closure has captured `i` to be 10.

To get around this, you reduce the scope of the closure, by introducing a variable *inside the loop*, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // Closure extends to here.
    var copy = i;

    // **copy** is captured
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { DoWork("closure", copy); });
}
```

Here, the closure doesn't extend beyond the loop, but just to the value inside.

That said, the second call to the [`QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem.aspx) produces the desired result because you've created the [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) at the time that the delegate is being queued up, the value is fixed at that point.

Note that [in C# 5.0, the behavior for `foreach` was changed because it happens so often (where the closure closes over the loop) and causes a number of people a lot of headaches](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) (but not `for` like you are using).

If you want to take advantage of that fact, you can call the [`Range` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) on the [`Enumerable` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) to use `foreach`:

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
{
    // Closure for anonymous function call begins here.
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { DoWork("closure", i); });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because of how variables are captured: the delegate will take the value of `i` at the time of actual execution, not at the time of declaration, so by that time they're all 10. Try a copy to a local variable:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int j = i;        
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate { DoWork("closure", j); });
```

Comment: i see.  thanks!  if I saw that code without knowing this I'd think "wtf - why make a copy???"